# R: finding an archived package in RCRAN Archives (splines)

Tags: r, package, archive, splines

I'm looking for the "splines" package, and it doesn't seem to exist anymore?! Someone told me that you can find it in rcran Archives- does anyone know how to do that?

Thanks~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `splines` package that comes installed with base R. Try loading it, and if that does not work let us know more details about your existing installation of R.

Load the package:

```
library(splines)
```

Get more information on the package:

```
library(help = splines)
```